# Societally Imposed Divorce

Tags: divorce

Sometimes we meet couples who have readily divorced but who clearly should not have done so - or at least not till common processes available to endangered marriages were tried.

Then again, we sometimes meet couples whose marriage is never going to end - although all family members desperately wish for it, as do neighbours and acquaintances.

The former group deserve our compassion and perhaps our gentle encouragement to reconsider.

The latter however usually belong to the human type that admit no superior - and hence take no advice. No amount of human misery or neurological damage to work-colleagues or even their own children will make them see that the only remedy for their situation is a separation from their present partner.

In the latter circumstances, is it not reasonable and sensible for a civilized society to step in and say enough is enough: this marriage is a stain on an entire community and must end ?

And if it is, then isn't there a legitimate basis for society's courts to impose a societal action upon the miserable couple to live apart ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148521/discussion-on-question-by-trunk-societally-imposed-divorce); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

In the US I can't imagine this not being in conflict with freedom of association (particularly intimate association) and the right to privacy.  Both of these are Constitutional Concepts, not called out specifically, but are generally taken as givens.   I suppose if a society as a whole decided that giving up individual freedom and allowing some group the right to decide how they should live their lives it could work, but the US is not that place.

As a matter of personal opinion I find the idea of someone else stepping into the institution of marriage repugnant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148519/discussion-between-michael-hall-and-trunk).